# Average of multiple survey responses (columns)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I feel a bit embarrassed for asking this but here goes:

I'm using Excel 2010 and I have a worksheet containing 700+ customer satisfaction survey responses. Each row is a survey with a 1-5 or NA response to 5 questions. It looks like the following:

```
+-Agent--+--Q1--+--Q2--+--Q3--+
|        |      |      |      |
| Jeff   |  5   |  5   |  5   |
+--------+------+------+------+
| James  |  1   |  1   |  1   |
+--------+------+------+------+
| Jack   |  5   |  5   |  5   |
+--------+------+------+------+
| Jeff   |  3   |  NA  |  5   |
+--------+------+------+------+
| Jeff   |  NA  |  NA  |  3   |
+--------+------+------+------+
| James  |  5   |  5   |  5   |
+--------+------+------+------+
| ...    |  ... |  ... |  ... |
+--------+------+------+------+
```

I want to create a worksheet listing each agent in column A and the average of all of questions answered regarding them. I tried a formula like `AVERAGEIF(SurveyResponses!A2:A7,A2,SurveyResponses!B2:D7)` where `A2` contains the agent's name, but it doesn't appear to work properly.

For example, I get a 5.00 average for some agents when it should be a 4.61. When I look in the Function Arguments screen for my AVERAGEIF on this person, it *looks* like it recognizes the values properly. The Average_rage shows `{"NA","NA","NA","NA",1;5,5,5,5,5;5,...` but the returned value below that says `= 5` which is not right since there is a `1`.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: I just tested this with your sample data. Looks good to me. I assume you are dragging your formula down to capture multiple Agent names. If that assumption is correct, did you lock the references, so it should read: `AVERAGEIF(SurveyResponses!$A$2:$A$7,A2,SurveyResponses!$B$2:$D$7)`

Comment: Yes, but not initially. I left that detail out. Only A2 was left unlocked. I even tried selecting the columns rather than specific ranges of cells since I don't have any totals on this sheet.

Comment: When I look in the Function Arguments screen for my AVERAGEIF, it _looks_ like it recognizes the values properly.. E.g., Average_rage shows `{"NA","NA","NA","NA",1;5,5,5,5,5;5,...` but the returned value below that says `= 5` which is not right since there is a `1`

Comment: No, I expect it to ignore the individual NA's.

Comment: Can you post your exact data set?

Comment: I guess my issue is that in the example data I provided, I expect to get `4.33 = (5+5+5+3+5+3) / 6` but instead I get 4.00 and I'm trying to understand why. When I replace the NA's with 1, I expect `3.22 = (5+5+5+3+1+5+1+1+3) / 9` but the formula gives 3.00.

Comment: See my answer, you are only averaging one column (column B) with that formula......

Comment: I accepted barry's answer, but @ScottHoltzman thanks taking time to try to help with this. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVERAGEIF` works like `SUMIF`, the second range used is actually the same size and shape as the first range, starting with the top left cell, so when you use this

`=AVERAGEIF(SurveyResponses!A2:A7,A2,SurveyResponses!B2:D7)`

because the first range is a single column then the second range used must be too (there's a 1 to 1 relationship between the cells) so because the top left cell in SurveyResponses!B2:D7 is SurveyResponses!B2 the range begins there and is the same size and shape as SurveyResponses!A2:A7

....so you are actually getting this....

=AVERAGEIF(SurveyResponses!A2:A7,A2,SurveyResponses!`B2:B7`)

AVERAGEIF help does tell you that but it isn't very clear

If you want the ranges to be different sizes you need an "array formula" like this

`=AVERAGE(IF(SurveyResponses!A2:A7=A2,SurveyResponses!B2:D7))`

You need to confirm that with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` so that curly braces appear around the formula in the formula bar. That formula will count any blanks as zeroes but ignore text values like NA

Comment: this works perfectly. Thank you. After reading the first few search results for array formulas, I'm still having a really hard time understanding when and why to use them. Right now, when someone says to do it, I just do it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this would be a pivot table.  They look scary, but they're fairly easy to use.  Rows = names, Columns = Q, Average for the answers.

Comment: I'm familiar with PivotTables and I know I can average the values of each question (column), but I'm not understanding how I could use PivotTables to get the **total** average.